# Create interactive network diagram from rails database

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

This is probably a little ambitious given I've just started Rails but I really want to understand how to interact visually with the data I can collect in my Rails application. The application is pretty simple social network type app with an emphasis on the connections between people and the number of interactions between them. I would like to end up with a network diagram similar to [here](http://js.cytoscape.org/demos/29419ca0e6430a7185a5/) or this one in [d3.js](http://projects.flowingdata.com/tut/interactive_network_demo/) to illustrate the relationship between users. I would like to enable users to remove relationships between nodes and for this to be written back to the Rails database so I guess this needs a two way data binding approach.

So the question is what is the best approach to this? I have read about Angular.js to provide the databinding and then I suppose a graphical javascript to interact with this but given I'm new to Rails this would be non-trivial so I wonder if there is an easier way? I have read for example about the [gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon) gem but I'm not sure if this is really a feasible solution for this kind of problem

Comment: You're really asking two questions: 1. What is the best way to create a visualization in the client, and how should the data it receives be structured to make that easiest? And 2. What is the best way to make Rails generate that data? You don't need to know anything about Rails to answer question #1, and you don't need to know anything about the client to answer #2, and you should approach them as completely separate problems. Trying to solve them both as though they are the same problem will just make your life more difficult.

Comment: Bit cryptic. I do need to know how to pass data from Rails to javascript and back again...

Comment: Use JSON. But the structure of the JSON depends on the answer to #1. Solve #1 first; #2 is the easy part.

Comment: "Two-way data binding" is a red herring. When people use that term with respect to JavaScript frameworks like Angular, they're talking about the binding between the client-side view and the client-side model. They're not talking about a binding between the the client and the server.